# Webform act as Warranty form

Tags: forms, webforms

I'm a newbie, working on a project which need to use the webform act as warranty form, the form got a date field. After the user submitted the form, the submission result page should show the expiry date of the warranty, but I don't know how the expiry date can be show?? Could anyone who can help me how to do that?? million thanks